# What happens when more than one web application has the same context root in jBoss?

Tags: deployment, jboss

We use jBoss in our development environment to deploy to. There are many applications deployed there for which the `context root` of the application is not necessarily named after the  `WAR`.

For example, the application may be called `abc_microsite` and have a `context root` of `Getoutoftrouble`.

**EAR pom.xml:**

```
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>company</groupId>
                        <artifactId>abc_microsite-war</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>Getoutoftrouble</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
```

What will happen if more than one `EAR` is deployed with the same `context root`? How will jBoss handle a request to http://server/Getoutoftrouble ? **OR** Will you get an error when you try to deploy the EAR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get an error on trying to deploy second context root with the same name.

It should be very easy to reproduce and check. :)

Comment: fair enough. I didn't want to try it if was going to break other people's projects. thanks